# How do I display the largest factor of an inputted number?

Tags: java

```
package Testing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

     public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input positive integer: ");
        int n = scan1.nextInt();

        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++){
            if (n % i == 0){
                System.out.print(n/i);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

When I run this code it ends up printing the numbers 2510 whenever I input 50. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You didn't stop at the first successful result. :P

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: *Hint:* It didn't actually print `2510`. It printed `2`, `5`, and `10` without any separators. If you change to `println`, you can see this.

Comment: @Andreas Actually it printed 25, 10.  50 was just the exact perfect choice of input to create this confusion.

Comment: @KevinAnderson DOH! Of course.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele My assignment was to print only the largest factor. It does this for some numbers I input, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you're very close, but you need to stop iterating after you find an answer. This can be done with the `break` keyword, which exits the innermost loop.

```
for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++){
    if (n % i == 0){
        System.out.print(n/i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop when you find the first prime factor. And do not forget, that in your example `Math.sqrt(n)` is calculated every loop.

```
public static int getLargestFactor(int num) {
    for (int i = 2, max = (int)Math.sqrt(num); i <= max; i++)
        if (num % i == 0)
            return num / i;

    return num;
}
```